# How do I find the font file named 'Heiti TC' on my mac?

Tags: font

I'm pretty sure this command runs successfully on my mac

```
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = ['Heiti TC']
```

which means the "Heiti TC" font installed correctly.

However, I don't find a font file named "Heiti" either in `/System/Library/Fonts` or `/Library/Fonts`. How do I find the font file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heiti TC is built into macOS.

You should be able to see it in Font Book, from where you can reveal in Finder at `/System/Library/Fonts/STHeiti Light.ttc` [also medium]

[image]

List of included fonts - [Apple KB - Fonts included with macOS Catalina](https://support.apple.com/HT210192) [was included long before Catalina, but I don't know from when]